# How to find difference of array item

Tags: ruby

How to find difference of two consecutive items in an array `["5 7", "2 2", "6 7", "10 4", "1 3", "6 7", "9 1", "7 8", "1 7", "4 6"]`.

Output should be [3, 5], [-4, -5], [-4, 3] etc.

[3,5] is from [5-2, 7-2].

I have the following but I am not sure how to proceed from here.

```
["5 7", "2 2", "6 7", "10 4", "1 3", "6 7", "9 1", "7 8", "1 7", "4 6"]
.each_cons(2){|a| # need more here }
```

Comment: Something looks wrong here. You are apparently wanting to process/parse some odd-looking `String` values e.g. `"5 7"`. Is there some reason you don't want the more conventional array-of-arrays and use `[5,7]` so your big array  would start `[ [5,7], [2,2], [6,7]`?

Comment: @Neil, it may be that shin was just given the data in that format.

Comment: @shin, this is almost the same as your previous question, which started with a more normal array. Can you explain what trouble you are having?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is one way you could do it, using Ruby's [Matrix](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.1.1/libdoc/matrix/rdoc/Matrix.html) class.  Below I mention a second method that does not use matrix operations, but I think the first reads better.  Both methods permit the strings in the array to contain more than two integers.

**Code**

```
require 'matrix'

def diff(arr)    
  arr.map { |str| str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }.each_cons(2).map { |e,f|
    (Matrix[e]-Matrix[f]).to_a }.flatten(1) 
end
```

**Example**

```
arr = ["5 7", "2 2", "6 7", "10 4", "1 3", "6 7", "9 1", "7 8", "1 7", "4 6"]
def diff(arr)
  #=> [[ 3, 5], [-4, -5], [-4, 3], [ 9, 1], [-5, -4],
  #    [-3, 6], [ 2, -7], [ 6, 1], [-3, 1]]
```

**Explanation**

For the above example, first convert the strings into arrays containing two integers:

```
b = arr.map { |str| str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }
  #=> [[5, 7],[2, 2],[6, 7],[10, 4],[1, 3],[6, 7],[9, 1],[7, 8],[1, 7],[4, 6]]
```

As you did, process each pair of arrays using [Enumerable#each_cons](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons):

```
c = b.each_cons(2)
  #=> #<Enumerator: [[5, 7], [2, 2], [6, 7], [10, 4], [1, 3],
  #    [6, 7], [9, 1], [7, 8], [1, 7], [4, 6]]:each_cons(2)>
```

To view the contents of this enumerator:

```
c.to_a
  #=> [[[ 5, 7], [2, 2]], [[2, 2], [6, 7]], [[6, 7], [10, 4]],
  #    [[10, 4], [1, 3]], [[1, 3], [6, 7]], [[6, 7], [ 9, 1]],
  #    [[ 9, 1], [7, 8]], [[7, 8], [1, 7]], [[1, 7], [ 4, 6]]]
```

Map each pair to differences:

```
d = c.map { |e,f| (Matrix[e]-Matrix[f]).to_a }
  #=> [[[3, 5]], [[-4, -5]], [[-4, 3]], [[9, 1]], [[-5, -4]],
  #    [[-3, 6]], [[2, -7]], [[6, 1]], [[-3, 1]]]
```

Lastly, flatten one level:

```
d.flatten(1) 
  #=> [[ 3, 5], [-4, -5], [-4, 3], [ 9, 1], [-5, -4],
  #    [-3, 6], [ 2, -7], [ 6, 1], [-3, 1]]
```

**Alternative**

It you'd prefer not using the Matrix class, within the `map` block you could use [Array#transpose](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-transpose) and [Enumerable#reduce](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-reduce) (aka `inject`):

```
arr.map { |str| str.scan(/\d+/).map(&:to_i) }.each_cons(2).map { |e| 
      e.transpose.map { |a| a.reduce(&:-) } }
```